# Programmatically create Azure Service Bus bindings for Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I am trying to dynamically create an Azure Function (Service Bus trigger) that will respond to messages from a Service Bus queue or topic.

There is a [CLI way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function-azure-cli?tabs=bash%2Cbrowser&pivots=programming-language-csharp) of creating an Azure Function that acts as an HTTP Trigger. However I havent found a way to create a Service Bus Trigger. Is this even doable ?

** Edit, I am able to programmatically create an Azure Service Bus Queue using [this sample code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-bus-dotnet-management)

So really I am hoping to create a function based on the details of the servicebus queue generated at an earlier step and have the function fire from that queue.

Comment: I believe you'll need to create an ARM template that will create the queue / topic, then create a new azure functions and specify the created queue / topic connection

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio That might be an option but it isnt elegant in my case. I am trying to dynamically create Service Bus Queues and then have Azure functions triggered by them. I have looked into dynamic configurations https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/enable-dynamic-configuration-azure-functions-csharp  curious if that may be the way ?

Comment: the ideal, you'd be if Service Bus could publish events on Event Grid, whenever a new queue / topic is created, but it's not available at this moment. (Your function could react to the event grid and perform the settings). I would go with the solution on my first comment, but I am not sure if there's a better way